# LOOP in MySQL - Incorrect Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I write a store procedure and I am getting below error while parsing :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CleanLog, Line 9 Incorrect
>   syntax near 'LOOP'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CleanLog,
>   Line 28 Incorrect syntax near 'LOOP'.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio   10.50.1600.1. Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CleanLog
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @DATE_VALUE CHAR(16);
  DECLARE DISTINCT_DATE_CUR CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT(CAST(INSERT_DATE AS DATE)) AS INSERT_DATE FROM RECORD_TABLE ORDER BY INSERT_DATE;

  OPEN DISTINCT_DATE_CUR;

  read_loop: LOOP

    FETCH DISTINCT_DATE_CUR INTO @DATE_VALUE;

    BEGIN
              BEGIN TRY

                     BEGIN TRANSACTION
                           DELETE FROM RECORD_TABLE WHERE CAST(INSERT_DATE AS DATE) = @DATE_VALUE;
                     COMMIT TRANSACTION

              END TRY
              BEGIN CATCH
                     ROLLBACK
              END CATCH
       END

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE DISTINCT_DATE_CUR;

END
```

Comment: you are confused...Title says MYSQL , and Body says SQL Server? which one

Comment: maybe you mean mssql?